# Encrypt data in MS Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, search, encryption, amazon-rds

We have a requirement to store some data in a SQL Server database (on Amazon RDS) in a way that is not human-readable. It is not required for all tables, however a system that encrypted all tables would be OK.

The only real requirement is if someone gained access to the database (or one of our backups) the data in sensitive tables would be worthless to them, or at least impossible to read without a huge amount of effort.

However we do need to be able to search the data in these tables from within the (C#) app, hosted on a Windows server (which is hosted on Amazon EC2) and also output the data in a readable form in the app.

Can anyone suggest some options that are available to us? Preferably not one that consists of us having to buy our own SQL Server licence or host it ourselves - we are keen to continue with RDS if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is: choose the critical tables and columns that should be encrypted, choose an encryption method, and refresh these columns with encrypted data. Your front end C# app has to know which columns are encrypted, then it decrypts the data before outputting it or performing searches. In terms of the actual encryption method, SQL Server 2008 (or later) has inbuilt functions such as **EncryptByPassPhrase**, **DecryptByPassPhrase**, and **EncryptByCert**, **DecryptByCert**. If you follow this approach, your critical columns only store encrypted data. This technique is *column encryption*.

This approach should not require you to buy a SQL Server licence as it can all be done using native SQL commands. Also from my understanding of RDS, it's unlikely anyone could gain access to backups as they are hosted by Amazon. Your only other security concern is that when you create logins for people to access your database, limit their permissions so they don't have access to the tables storing the secure data.

Finally I should add I am new to Amazon RDS myself, and these encryption techniques are something I've come across while researching how to migrate to the cloud. However the principles should be sound and workable.